# Login em Angular2

Tags: angular

Estou a começar a aprender `angular2` e estou com umas pequenas duvidas acerca de como fazer um login para uma aplicação.

Por exemplo eu no `php` faço um `query` com as variáveis que recebo por `post` verifico se existem, se existirem crio uma `session` e em todas as páginas verifico se a `session` está activo.

No `angular2` não sei como fazer isso. Alguém me pode ajudar?

Comment: Um exemplo completo com login:
http://kazale.com/curso-angular-2-aula-1-criando-primeira-aplicacao/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Olá, MANIAMAX!

Essa dúvida é frequente em iniciantes em angular, principalmente os que vem de back-end de php e afins.

A forma de autenticação em angular é feita usando tokens. Você irá fazer um request pro servidor com email e senha. A partir disso, o servidor faz a verificação e se estiver ok, ele enviará um token. Esse token deverá ser guardado pelo cliente.

E o que fazer com esse token?

Você irá utiliza-lo para verificar o login.

A forma de detectar esse token no servidor pode ser várias. Você pode inseri-lo no próprio request, envia-lo como parâmetro ou verificar o cache do navegador.

O token é único para cada usuário.

Espero que tenha solucionado sua dúvida. Poderia fazer um exemplo, mas pelo que entendi, sua dúvida é mais como funciona do que como fazer.

Comment: Coloca o exemplo mesmo assim, vai enriquecer tua resposta.

Comment: Teria algum exemplo Pedro? Sou novo com o framework

Comment: engraçado que todo mundo sabe explicar mas ninguém pode colocar um exemplo